# Push AJAX retrieved JSON into Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, datatables

I'm using the datatables plugin and it's working fine for me. However, I'm making multiple calls to populate multiple tables, when I know I could make one AJAX call and store the results in a variable and have each table function use that variable for its data, but I can't get it to work.

I'm using something like to to get the data I need.

```
var all_data;

$.ajax({
        async   : false,
        url: 'all_data.php',
        type: 'GET',     
        success: function(data) {

        all_data = data;
         console.log(all_data);
 }

  })
```

The idea is to pass `all_data` variable into my table function (I have several on this one page) without having to make multiple calls. Doing the following returns one column with the letter "a", which isn't right. The data that comes back is JSON coded. I've used the below code, but with the AJAX function as part of the table function:

```
$("#my_table").DataTable({
      "data":all_data
       ,
      "paging":        true,
      "sDom": '<"top">t<"bottom"><"clear">',
      "pageLength": 50,
      "order": [[ 4, "desc" ]],
      "aoColumns": [
      { "bSortable": true, "width": "0%", "sClass": "lang_body_2", "sTitle": "","visible":false },
      { "bSortable": true, "searchable": false, "width": "10%", "sClass": "lang_body_2 table_names", "sTitle": "" },
      { "bSortable": true, "searchable": false,"width": "20%", "sClass": "lang_body_2",  "sTitle": "Database","visible":false},
      { "bSortable": true, "searchable": false ,"width": "20%","sClass": "lang_body_2","sTitle": "National Average","visible":false },
      { "bSortable": true, "searchable": false ,"width": "50%","sClass": "lang_body_2 index_num table_index","sTitle": "" },
      ],
      "columns": [
      { "searchable": true },
      { "searchable": false },
      { "searchable": false },
      { "searchable": false },
      { "searchable": false },
      ],
      "search": {
      "search": "gen"
      },
      "columns": [
      { "width": "20%" },
      null,
      null,
      null,
      { "width": "80%" },
      ],
      "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
        colorIndex();}
      });
});
```

What am I doing wrong here? I'm suspecting I have to prepare `all_data` somehow, but I'm not sure what that might be.

EDIT: If I console.log the data returned, this is what I get (cut off for brevity):

```
 Object {draw: 0, recordsTotal: 484, recordsFiltered: 484, data: Array[484]}
 data: Array[484]
    [0 … 99]
     0: Array[5]
          0: "edu"1: "High School"2: "37.90"3: "49.70"4: "76"length: 5
```

Comment: #my_table have <th> cols defined?

Comment: Could you post a sample of how you create the json on server side (and a sample of json respone too) ?

Comment: @Murali Yes. If I put the AJAX call as part of the table function (versus outside) the table loads up fine.

Comment: @phillip100 Just added an update to my question with a sample of the JSON which comes back via `encode_JSON`. I'm guessing the format isn't quite right, but this works if I put the AJAX call inside the datatables function, so not clear why it doesn't work when I take it out of the function.

Comment: did you tried to do instead of   "data":all_data  use "data":all_data.data ?

Comment: @kabstergo I think I've tried every iteration of this and similar, but unfortunately, that didn't work.

Comment: @jonmrich , make jsfiddle. I can't reproduce your issue - http://jsfiddle.net/philip100/5sf4ejzk/ - seems to work fine for me... Are you sure your `all_data ` is set before you call `element.DataTable()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, the only thing you need to do is
Assign your datatable to a variable and then in your ajax resolve clear, add data and draw the table.

```
var all_data;
$.ajax({
        async   : false,
        url: 'all_data.php',
        type: 'GET',     
        success: function(data) {

        all_data = data;
        console.log(all_data);
        table.clear().row.add(all_data).draw(); //clear, add data and draw

 }

  });


// Assign your datatable to a variable
var table = $("#my_table").DataTable({
      "data":all_data
       ,
      "paging":        true,
      "sDom": '<"top">t<"bottom"><"clear">',
      "pageLength": 50,
      "order": [[ 4, "desc" ]],
      "aoColumns": [
      { "bSortable": true, "width": "0%", "sClass": "lang_body_2", "sTitle": "","visible":false },
      { "bSortable": true, "searchable": false, "width": "10%", "sClass": "lang_body_2 table_names", "sTitle": "" },
      { "bSortable": true, "searchable": false,"width": "20%", "sClass": "lang_body_2",  "sTitle": "Database","visible":false},
      { "bSortable": true, "searchable": false ,"width": "20%","sClass": "lang_body_2","sTitle": "National Average","visible":false },
      { "bSortable": true, "searchable": false ,"width": "50%","sClass": "lang_body_2 index_num table_index","sTitle": "" },
      ],
      "columns": [
      { "searchable": true },
      { "searchable": false },
      { "searchable": false },
      { "searchable": false },
      { "searchable": false },
      ],
      "search": {
      "search": "gen"
      },
      "columns": [
      { "width": "20%" },
      null,
      null,
      null,
      { "width": "80%" },
      ],
      "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
        colorIndex();}
      });
});
```

Comment: @jonmrich can you please accept the answer if this resolve your issue. Thanks